# What article can I use to refer to a thing correctly?

Tags: articles

Which of the two sentences is correct (and why):

> Elle se cogne contre de table.

or

> Elle se cogne contre la table.

Comment: Just out of curiousity : why would you use the first (erroneous) sentence? Knowing **why** you actually make the mistake is actually more helpful than giving you broad rules about what the correct form is.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I'll remember your useful advice. Basically I thought of «de» as corresponding to «the» in English.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora Prepositions vary a lot between language, but *de* as a preposition is often translated by *the*. In a partitive article, it would be *de la* followed by an uncountable noun which *table* isn't.

Comment: @Gilles, Merçi. Yes indeed as preposition :-) as in «Je voudrais reserver des billets de train, svp». Well clarified by your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence is correct

> Elle se cogne contre la table.

*La* or *le* or *les* are definite articles. *De* isn't.